# The role of the "return" value and an unexpected result from a programme

Tags: python, return

First, I'd like to say I'm new to coding. I enrolled on a Python course a few days ago; I had never had any experience with coding before.

I have a question concerning the "return" command (or whaterver it's called in the parlance). I know its textbook definition - it is supposed to return a function's value to the caller - but I nonetheless don't understand what it really does...

Let's say I have a function:

```
def your_salary(a, b)
    salary = a * b #a is the number of hours worked, b is a rate per hour
```

Now I want to use the function so I call the function in the script and calculate a salary so I write:

```
your_salary(40, 12) #40 hours worked for 12$ each
```

The programme does nothing.

When I add the built-in print function to my function, I'll get a correct result:

```
def your_salary(a, b)
    salary = a * b
    print(salary)

your_salary(40, 12)

=> 480
```

When I replace the print function with "return", I get nothing again. To me it looks like "return" does not return the value to the caller. When I called the function, it returned nothing, the programme did not show me the result of the calculation defined in the function your_salary. I guess that's the reason why I don't understand what it means for "return" to return a value to its caller. Any helpful explanations?

Comment: You do not have the word `return` anywhere in your code.  If you say `return salary` in the function, and `print(your_salary(40,12))`, it will do as you expect.  Running just `your_salary(40,12)` does not print anything (unless you are in the interactive interpreter).

Answer (score 1):

Printing some variable value into the console using `print` function is not the same as returning a value from a function. Your function is printting `salary` variable into console but `your_salary` is returning `None` value.

```
def your_salary(a, b)
    salary = a * b
    return salary

result = your_salary(40, 12)
# I guess you are using an interactive shell or similar
result
=> 480 # Returned value
```

Answer (score 0):

Note this session in an interactive interpreter:

```
Python 3.7.3 (v3.7.3:ef4ec6ed12, Mar 25 2019, 22:22:05) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32 
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.                       
>>> def your_salary(a,b):                                                                    
...     salary = a*b                                                                         
...     return salary                                                                        
...                                                                                          
>>> your_salary(9,200)                                                                       
1800                                                                                         
>>> print(your_salary(9,200))                                                                
1800                                                                                         
>>> i = your_salary(9,200)                                                                   
>>> i                                                                                        
1800                                                                                         
>>>
```

For each line you enter in the interactive interpreter, if that line returned a value, it will print the value.  The `print` function doesn't return a value, so the only thing we see is the side effect of the `print` function itself.  That's something that doesn't happen when running script.

Compare that to running this code non-interactively:

```
C:\tmp>cat x.py
def your_salary(a,b):
    salary = a*b
    return salary

your_salary(9,200)
print("Now!")
print(your_salary(9,200))

C:\tmp>python x.py
Now!
1800

C:\tmp>
```

Note that nothing is printed unless we have a specific `print` function.

Answer (score 0):

## What `return` does

When you call a function in an expression:

```py
def foo(val):
    return val - 1

x = 5
x + foo(x) / 10
```

The function `foo` is executed, and the call `foo(x)` is replaced with the return value from `foo`:

```py
x = 5
x + {{ result from calling foo(x) }} / 10
```

In the specific example above, we know that `foo(x)` consists of `x - 1`, so the return value in this case should be `4`:

```py
x = 5
x + 4 / 10
```

**`return` is used to pass data from inside the function to the caller of the function.**

## What's wrong with your code

**You didn't `return` anything.**

In Python, if you omit `return` from a function, it returns `None`. Therefore, the `your_salary` function effectively discards its result, and calls to `your_salary` always evaluate to `None`.

This

```py
def your_salary(hours, rate)
    salary = hours * rate

your_salary(40, 12)
```

evaluates to

```py
def your_salary(hours, rate)
    salary = hours * rate

None
```

Oops!

## How to fix it

**Use `return`.**

This

```py
def your_salary(hours, rate)
    salary = hours * rate
    return salary

your_salary(40, 12)
```

evaluates to

```py
def your_salary(hours, rate)
    salary = hours * rate
    return salary

480
```

## What about `print()`?

As the other answers mentioned, `print` emits text to the console.

**Printing bypasses your program entirely**.

Use it to communicate information in text form with the user. Do not use it communicate data within your program.